# Swarm plots in Plotly / plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly

you can do Plotly.Scatter with the 'jitter' argument but that seems to scatter randomly. Notice how neatly these are spaced out in Seaborn? Can that be replicated in Plotly?

[image: Seaborn 'Swarm' Plots]

Answer (score 9):

See [`strip`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.strip.html) from `plotly.express`.

[image]

Comment: Jittering is better than nothing, but the point of beeswarm plots is to explicitly show the shape of the distribution. Jittering does not make the shape of the distribution apparent. It mostly makes the range of the data apparent, due to the tendency of points in dense regions to crowd on each other.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, no, but there is an option `points="all"` to the `px.box` function that would add the swarm plot to the left side of the box. The example below is taken [from the plotly documentation page about boxplot](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/)

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, x="time", y="total_bill", points="all")
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]